# use yield and return in a read_file function

Tags: python, yield

I am writing a simple tool to read my files, which should be able to distinguish if the given path points to a certain file or the root path of the files.

my code is like this:

```py
ALL_SEQ = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10']

def read_pose_txt(filepath):
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        return np.loadtxt(filepath)
    elif os.path.isdir(filepath):
        for seq in ALL_SEQ:
            filepath_x = os.path.join(filepath, (str(seq)+".txt"))
            yield np.loadtxt(filepath_x)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("wrong filepath")
```

but when I give the path to a certain file, this function also produce a generator instead of simple **return** the loaded txt.

why couldn't I use return and yield in the same function? Is there a better way to accomplish my goal of such a smart file-reader?

Best Regards

Zhe

Comment: If a function contains **any** `yield` statement then it returns a generator, so it is not permitted also to have a `return` statement with a value. You can have a `return` **without** a value in a function that contains `yield`.

Comment: @alaniwi: It’s not that it’s not permitted, it’s just always a generator.

Comment: Technically, you can return a value, but that value will simply be used to instantiate `StopIteration`. (Clearly not what the OP wants, though.)

Comment: @chepner `SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator`

Comment: You can work around this by putting the generator part in a separate function or by using a generator expression instead of `yield`, but having a function that works like this is kind of questionable in the first place. When calling the function, you need to know the type it’s going to return anyway, because generators of file contents and single file contents behave very differently, so you should probably either a) have two functions or b) always return a list.

Comment: @alaniwi: Old version of Python?

Comment: The question is, do you want to yield file objects, or do you want to yield elements *from* the file objects? (I.e., do you want to use `yield` in both cases or `yield from` in both cases?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a generator, `yield` statements yield the results of the generator function. You should always use `yield` to yield results. If there is only one result, then yield only once.

So, I guess you want to replace this:

```
return np.loadtxt(filepath)
```

with this:

```
yield np.loadtxt(filepath)
return
```

It is valid to `return` from a generator, but you cannot return a value that way.

---

BTW: Actually, `return x` is valid in Python 3, the return value ends up in an exception, which is a feature tailored specifically for the very special case of async await framework. Until you really know what you are doing, it would be best to just treat that as forbidden.

If you have `yield` in a function, use only empty `return`, signaling the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if`s are backwards: if the path is a directory, you call `loadtxt`; if it is a file, you loop over calls to `loadtxt`.

Comment: True, but fixing this won’t solve the problem mentioned in the question.

Comment: sry, I fixed that.